# Line up list with checkbox

Tags: html, css

Now i have this html code:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <input checked="checked" id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" type="checkbox" value="true">
    <div class="login-link">
      Запомнить меня
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/users/sign_up" class="login-link">Регистрация</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="/users/sign_up" class="login-link">Забыли пароль?</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

all here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/4GtKQ/

Also see the image:

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/59666091/checkbox.png]

But why am I getting such space between "Запомнить меня" and "Регистрация"? How to set them in normal line-grid?

Comment: I cannot see the relationship of that image and that fiddle page

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss resize preview subwindow in jsfiddle

Comment: Why to close? Question is good! And problem is described normally!

Comment: I used the "share full screen" link http://jsfiddle.net/4GtKQ/embedded/result/ so I can see it there!

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss what i can say.... you are blind... of course there will be not images..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox and the associated text take up a different amount of vertical space.  The extra space you're pointing to is the result of both elements lining up along the top edge of their *box*.

Assuming you want the text and the input to have the same baseline *and* have the text aligned with the left edge and the checkbox aligned with the right edge, the finished markup and CSS would be like this:

HTML:

```
<li class="remember">
  <label>Запомнить меня 
    <input checked="checked" id="user_remember_me" name="user[remember_me]" 
           type="checkbox" value="true">
  </label>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
li.remember { 
    text-align: left;
}
li.remember input { 
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4GtKQ/1/

Comment: thank's, also could you take a look at my footer? why on every page it's margin is deferent?

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously because of the check box, and I am sure that you can get a way around it, but I suggest you separate them out to be separate elements then line them up with CSS. Check box doesn't necessarily have to have a label associated to it, just make sure it has a title for users who have accessibility needs.

Sorry I can't give you an exact resolution, the language it is written in is very difficult for me too read, if you can provide a actual web address (full web page) I think in this case you would get more of a responses as we can use things like Chrome's Inspect Element. Don't get more wrong the JSfiddle is great, but this is an exception.

Comment: There's no good reason *not* to have a `label` associated with a checkbox.  Having a `label` associated with a checkbox greatly improves usability, especially for users who have poor dexterity (a block of text is easier to click than a tiny checkbox).

Comment: it is generated from sass+haml

Comment: I agree in principle that it should indeed have a label, but in this case I would say that you could spend a very long time fiddling with this, and going round in circles (what I the author has done already).

Answer (score -2):

```
<li style="position:relative; top: -5px;">
 <a href="/users/sign_up" class="login-link">Регистрация</a>
</li>
```

Comment: never ever use relative positioning to fix this kind of issue where a clear textflow can solve everything in a very nice way.